# Program to watch secondary monitor's picture in the main monitor

Tags: gratis, display

We display fullscreen data in a projector whose source is the secondary monitor. Sometimes the picture of the projector cannot be viewed by the operator of the computer so we need a control window on the main monitor where we can see what the projector display.

Is there such a program? Something like the little live preview in the Windows taskbar, when you hover over a program, or the magnifier app that you can dock and place the cursor in the second screen.

Only requirement is that is should be free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com/)

As you can see on the image below you can create scenes and from the many available sources you can add one or more monitor/desktop to this scene so you can observe even multiple monitors through the program, or place this scene on full-screen on another monitor. The cursor is displayed too. For this and the reasons below, **this is the perfect solution**:

- Many other advanced options
- Free
- Open source
- Cross-platform

[image: Open Broadcaster Software displaying second monitor]

Comment: This is a very solid solution. As an addition, since the original poster was using Windows, to do this: (1) install OBS, (2) On Sources, click on "+", (3) select Display Capture, (4) Choose the external monitor. // Note if you are running a video on the external monitor, the video may stop upon opening OBS, but you simply just have to resume the video again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/), using the same computer as both the host and the client, [specifying in the options](https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/341/12/can-i-view-only-one-of-the-displays-of-my-multiple-monitor-computer?) to mirror only the projector's display. Assuming you're using Windows, look for the **DisplayDevice** parameter under VNC server properties

- Open **VNC Server Options**
- Navigate to the **Expert** tab
- Select **DisplayDevice**

The display syntax is as below:

```
\\.\DISPLAY1
```

> This may or may not be your primary monitor. In a standard right-ordered monitor configuration, they should be ordered Display1, Display2, Display3 and so on. However, to confirm, check your display enumeration in VNC Server > Information Center > Diagnostics.

It's sort of hackish, but it's a viable work-around.